LWC equivalent of lightning:unsavedChanges?
I have an LWC component that maintains state for changes the user is doing, without immediately updating those changes into the underlying records. I therefore run the risk of the user "navigating" to a new record or alternative page and losing those changes.
If I were developing an Aura component, I could perhaps use the lightning:unsavedChanges component (though I understand this isn't compatible with Digital Experiences). Using the beforeunload DOM event doesn't work for me, since the Salesforce UI is a Single Page Application. It may be that I should use the popstate DOM event, though I'm not sure that will do everything I need.
Is there an official way of handling this sort of thing when developing stateful LWCs that is compatible with the Salesforce UI and with Digital Experiences?
With the sinking feeling there's no good solution here, I raised an idea.

WARNING: This is a solution based on an experimental API only available in the Chromium browser family. It is not supported by Safari or Firefox.
I tried using the beforeunload event, but since the Salesforce UI is a Single Page Application, this is a total bust. I also tried using the popstate event, but this doesn't get triggered by in-app links (such as links to records, tabs and the like).
I turned to the Navigation API after this was mentioned by Jeff Kranz over on SFXD (discord server). This is, unfortunately, not yet a ratified part of the Web APIs but certainly (mostly) ticks the boxes I need to tick.
Here's an example of how unsaved change handling could work in an LWC using this API (tested in the Salesforce UI, but not in Digital Experiences at this point), on an org with Lightning Web Security enabled.
The HTML template:
<template>
    <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Simulate unsaved" onchange={handleChange} checked={unsavedChanges}></lightning-input>
</template>

The JS "controller":
import {LightningElement, api} from 'lwc';
import LightningConfirm from 'lightning/confirm';

/**
 * Experimental block navigation for unsaved changes.
 */
export default class Poc2 extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId; // Not actually used in this experiment

    /**
     * Tracks (simulated) unsaved changes, being true when there are some.
     *
     * @type {boolean}
     */
    unsavedChanges = false;

    /**
     * Holds the target URL during presentation of the confirmation dialog so a navigation can be completed if
     * allowed. Set to null when the dialog isn't being presented.
     *
     * @type {string|null}
     */
    target = null;

    /**
     * This lifecycle method is used to set up handling of navigate events, if the navigation API is supported.
     */
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log("XXX connected");

        // Only do processing on browsers that support the (currently experimental) navigation API
        if (window.navigation !== undefined) {
            console.log("XXX adding navigate event listener");

            // Listen to the navigate event the navigation API generates. This should probably be arranged to
            // allow removing the event listener in the disconnectedCallback too, though the latter doesn't
            // seem to be called much when navigating the Salesforce UI's SPA
            window.navigation.addEventListener('navigate', async (event) => {
                console.log("XXX navigation attempt noticed", event);

                // The "unsavedChanges" property is tracking whether there are changes that the user has not
                // yet saved
                if (this.unsavedChanges) {
                    // Salesforce can generate two navigations, which appears to be due to the event cancellation
                    // done here (though that isn't verified). The workaround is to remember the first navigation,
                    // which is the one the user initiates, and ignore any others that happen during this process.
                    // That's done by capturing the URL for the first navigation as a property ("target") and using
                    // it to complete the navigation if the user permits it.
                    const first = !this.target;

                    if (first) {
                        // It's the first event, so capture the URL
                        this.target = event.destination.url;
                    }

                    // Prevent the navigation this event would perform
                    event.preventDefault();

                    // We only want the confirm dialog shown and handled for the first event
                    if (first) {
                        // Show a non-blocking confirm dialog
                        const userConfirmed = await LightningConfirm.open({
                            message: "Unsaved changes will be lost",
                            variant: 'header',
                            label: 'Confirm Navigation'
                        });

                        // To ensure appropriate handling once the user has interacted with the dialog, get a local
                        // copy of the target URL then update the component's state (we are finished with the
                        // sequence of events that were triggered)
                        const target = this.target;
                        this.target = null;

                        if (userConfirmed) {
                            // Allow navigation
                            console.log("XXX user allowed navigation");

                            // Make sure we don't erroneously block the navigation that will now happen
                            this.unsavedChanges = false;

                            // Go to the destination URL for that first event
                            window.navigation.navigate(target);
                        } else {
                            // Prevent navigation
                            console.log('XXX navigation cancelled by the user');
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log("XXX no navigation API");
        }
    }

    /**
     * A simple handler for the checkbox control used to allow simulating unsaved changes.
     *
     * @param e the change event. Will not be null.
     */
    handleChange(e) {
        this.unsavedChanges = e.target.checked;

        console.log("XXX now ", this.unsavedChanges);
    }
}

And finally, the metadata file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>60.0</apiVersion>
    <description>Experimental block navigation for unsaved changes</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Poc 2</masterLabel>

    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    </targets>

    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="recordId" type="String"/>
        </targetConfig>

        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="recordId" type="String" default="{!recordId}"/>
        </targetConfig>

        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="recordId" type="String" default="{!recordId}"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>

This component can be dropped into a page and used to block navigations when its "Simulate unsaved" checkbox is checked. If this is unchecked, navigation should happen as normal.
BTW, the navigation after confirmation isn't ideal, as it actually triggers a full page navigation (it seems) rather than the SPA optimized page navigation, but it's good enough. There's also a bit of a visual glitch as the dialog gets displayed, but I can live with that since it sorts itself out and doesn't seem to cause issues.
As a reminder: at the time of writing, this only works in Chromium family browsers like Chrome and MS Edge.
I am not accepting my own answer since it isn't compatible with all browsers, but wanted to share my findings.
